# Application does not accept the log in credentials when build in release mode but works perfectly fine when build with debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on an application for vendors in visual studio. When I build my program using debug mode it works perfectly fine but when done the same using release mode, application runs without error but it does not take the same login credentials that I am giving for debug mode.

Kindly suggest some possible suggestions.

Comment: where are your login credentials validated? What is the authentication mode. Do you have 2 web.config in your application, one for release and another for debug with different connection strings. Clean the solution in release mode and rebuild.

Comment: As @Amit said, you could have multiple web.config files in your project, Web.config.Debug and Web.config.Release.

Comment: i have just one app.config file in my project

Comment: What kind of application is this? By that I mean, is this a website and/or is it hosted in IIS or IISExpress, or is this a console application, or a UWP app, etc.

Comment: this is a wpf,  @BurnsBA